# В параметрах функции я указываю количество кнопок, которые должны остаться в итоге, все остальные должны убраться

Tags: javascript, функции

В параметрах функции я указываю количество кнопок, которые должны остаться в итоге, все остальные должны убраться, но они остаются. Помогите пожалуйста решить эту задачу

```
function s(){
    setLocation(3);
}
function setLocation(quantityButtons){
    document.getElementById('locationButton1').style.visibility="hidden";
    document.getElementById('locationButton2').style.visibility="hidden";
    document.getElementById('locationButton3').style.visibility="hidden";
    document.getElementById('locationButton4').style.visibility="hidden";
    document.getElementById('locationButton5').style.visibility="hidden";
    alert(1);
    var i = 0;
    while(i<quantityButtons){
        alert(i);
        i++;
    }
       if(i==1){
           a(1);
       }else if(i==2){
           a(1,1);
       }else if(i==3){
           a(1,1,1);
       }else if(i==4){
           a(1,1,1,1);
       }else if(i==5){
           a(1,1,1,1,1);
       }
}
function a(one){
    document.getElementById('locationButton1').style.visibility="visible";
}
function a(one, two){
    document.getElementById('locationButton1').style.visibility="visible";
    document.getElementById('locationButton2').style.visibility="visible";
}
function a(one, two, three){
    alert(1);
    document.getElementById('locationButton1').style.visibility="visible";
    document.getElementById('locationButton2').style.visibility="visible";
    document.getElementById('locationButton3').style.visibility="visible";
}
function a(one, two, three, fore){
    document.getElementById('locationButton1').style.visibility="visible";
    document.getElementById('locationButton2').style.visibility="visible";
    document.getElementById('locationButton3').style.visibility="visible";
    document.getElementById('locationButton4').style.visibility="visible";
}
function a(one, two, three, fore, five){
    document.getElementById('locationButton1').style.visibility="visible";
    document.getElementById('locationButton2').style.visibility="visible";
    document.getElementById('locationButton3').style.visibility="visible";
    document.getElementById('locationButton4').style.visibility="visible";
    document.getElementById('locationButton5').style.visibility="visible";
}
```

Comment: И как по вашему движок должен понять какую из пяти функций `a` вызывать?

Comment: Не помню, как это называется в программировании, перегрузка функции вроде. На java например вызывается функция, в которой количество введённых параметров функции соответствует количеству входных параметров, Как это провернуть на javaScript?

Comment: В джаве есть, а тут нет.

Comment: Я поменял названия функций и дал им разные имена. Все равно не работает

Answer (score 0):

В javascript оказывется нет перегрузки функций. Я дал функциям разные имена и все заработало